# Python manage.py & Mysql all of a sudden don't work (Python manage.py run fine before without Mysql)

Tags: python, django, git, mysql-python

All of a sudden, after trying, to integrate React into Django following this [tutorial](http://geezhawk.github.io/using-react-with-django-rest-framework) `manage.py` Django stopped working. Every time I try to run the server or even try to find out the possible commands with `python manage.py` I get the following error:

```
(Python manage.py run fine before without Mysqldb)

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Brian\GOOGLE~1\Carmine\programs\Python\Django\RYASE_~1\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\mysql\base.py", line 25, in <module>
    import MySQLdb as Database
ImportError: No module named 'MySQLdb'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 22, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "C:\Users\Brian\GOOGLE~1\Carmine\programs\Python\Django\RYASE_~1\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 367, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "C:\Users\Brian\GOOGLE~1\Carmine\programs\Python\Django\RYASE_~1\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 341, in execute
    django.setup()
  File "C:\Users\Brian\GOOGLE~1\Carmine\programs\Python\Django\RYASE_~1\lib\site-packages\django\__init__.py", line 27, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "C:\Users\Brian\GOOGLE~1\Carmine\programs\Python\Django\RYASE_~1\lib\site-packages\django\apps\registry.py", line 108, in populate
    app_config.import_models(all_models)
  File "C:\Users\Brian\GOOGLE~1\Carmine\programs\Python\Django\RYASE_~1\lib\site-packages\django\apps\config.py", line 199, in import_models
    self.models_module = import_module(models_module_name)
  File "C:\Users\Brian\GOOGLE~1\Carmine\programs\Python\Django\RYASE_~1\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 986, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 969, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 958, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 673, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 662, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 222, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "C:\Users\Brian\Google Drive\Carmine\programs\Python\Django\Ryase_virtual_env\RayseV\authentication\models.py", line 7, in <module>
    from django.contrib.auth.models import (
  File "C:\Users\Brian\GOOGLE~1\Carmine\programs\Python\Django\RYASE_~1\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\models.py", line 4, in <module>
    from django.contrib.auth.base_user import AbstractBaseUser, BaseUserManager
  File "C:\Users\Brian\GOOGLE~1\Carmine\programs\Python\Django\RYASE_~1\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\base_user.py", line 52, in <module>
    class AbstractBaseUser(models.Model):
  File "C:\Users\Brian\GOOGLE~1\Carmine\programs\Python\Django\RYASE_~1\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 119, in __new__
    new_class.add_to_class('_meta', Options(meta, app_label))
  File "C:\Users\Brian\GOOGLE~1\Carmine\programs\Python\Django\RYASE_~1\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 316, in add_to_class
    value.contribute_to_class(cls, name)
  File "C:\Users\Brian\GOOGLE~1\Carmine\programs\Python\Django\RYASE_~1\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\options.py", line 214, in contribute_to_class
    self.db_table = truncate_name(self.db_table, connection.ops.max_name_length())
  File "C:\Users\Brian\GOOGLE~1\Carmine\programs\Python\Django\RYASE_~1\lib\site-packages\django\db\__init__.py", line 33, in __getattr__
    return getattr(connections[DEFAULT_DB_ALIAS], item)
  File "C:\Users\Brian\GOOGLE~1\Carmine\programs\Python\Django\RYASE_~1\lib\site-packages\django\db\utils.py", line 211, in __getitem__
    backend = load_backend(db['ENGINE'])
  File "C:\Users\Brian\GOOGLE~1\Carmine\programs\Python\Django\RYASE_~1\lib\site-packages\django\db\utils.py", line 115, in load_backend
    return import_module('%s.base' % backend_name)
  File "C:\Users\Brian\GOOGLE~1\Carmine\programs\Python\Django\RYASE_~1\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "C:\Users\Brian\GOOGLE~1\Carmine\programs\Python\Django\RYASE_~1\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\mysql\base.py", line 28, in <module>
    raise ImproperlyConfigured("Error loading MySQLdb module: %s" % e)
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Error loading MySQLdb module: No module named 'MySQLdb'
(RYASE_~1)
```

I already tried to install the `MySQLldb` with `MySQL-python` and `mysqlclient` as I'm using Python 3.x I've installed the MySQL Python manually but it installs under Python 2... So not too sure how to link it to Python 3

I've even tried to `git reset --hard` and `git clean` to reverse changes before the tutorial but the problem persists. I just can't see why the error would happen all of a sudden. I just wish to go back to the good all days where manage.py would run without Mysqldb

Answer (score 1):

Sorted, I deleted by mistake

```
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))
```

in settings.py

after adding the line the problem was fixed